# Add [nama_vendor] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Vendor] in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i would like to create an input for data vendor, but error showing `http://localhost:8000/vendor 500 (Internal Server Error)` and `Add [nama_vendor] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Vendor]`. i try to add `nama_vendor` in model but the error still shiowing.

this is my controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Vendor::Create([
            'nama_vendor' =>$request->nama_vendor,
            'no_hp' => $request->no_hp,
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'alamat' => $request->alamat,
            ]);
        return response()->json(['success'=>' Data Vendor Berhasil Disimpan.']);
    }
```

This is my View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$('#saveBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('Menyimpan...');
        $.ajax({
          data: $('#vendorForm').serialize(),
          url: "{{ route('vendor.store') }}",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
              $('#vendorForm').trigger("reset");
              $('#ajaxModal').modal('hide');
              $('#alertify-success').click();
              table.draw();
          },
          error: function (data) {
              console.log('Error:', data);
              $('#saveBtn').html('Simpan Data');
          }
      });
    });
</script>
```

this is My Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vendor extends Model
{
    protected $fillabel = ['nama_vendor','no_hp','email','alamat'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Spelling is Wrong In `Vendor` Model

Put `$fillable` instead of `$fillabel`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vendor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nama_vendor','no_hp','email','alamat'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of allyou have typo in your model. Not **$fillabel** it should be **$fillable**

Change this to.

```
  protected $fillable = ['nama_vendor','no_hp','email','alamat'];
```

Also, fix the following,

Vendor::Create.. should be Vendor::create.

Additionally, you can use following to make all attributes mass assignable

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request, Vendor $vendor)
{
    $vendor->create([
        'nama_vendor' =>$request->nama_vendor,
        'no_hp' => $request->no_hp,
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'alamat' => $request->alamat,
        ]);
    return response()->json(['success'=>' Data Vendor Berhasil Disimpan.']);
}
```

This should work and also fix type "$fillable"